# ES6 filter to return an array of object keys depending upon the parent key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a method which will help me return an array of the object keys of all the currencies based on a specific country. 
But, right now, what I get is list of all the currencies in an array.

I primarily need to use ES6 methods. I wouldn't want to use any other iterators.

For e.g. : What I need:

When I want the filter to be applied based on the country code 'US', it should return an array with currency ['USD'];

```
const myArr = Object.keys(myJSON.countries).filter((k) => (Object.keys(myJSON.countries[k].currencies)[0]) where country === 'US');
```

Output:
['USD']

This is in continuation of my previous question ->
[ES6 Map to return an array of object keys only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888412/es6-map-to-return-an-array-of-object-keys-only/48890169#48890169)

Could you please help me achieve this?
Here's the code:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('currencyList');
var myJSON = {
  "countryCode": {
  "Australia": "AU",
  "United States": "US",
  "Britain": "GB",
  "Japan": "JP",
  "India": "IND",
  "France": "FR",
  "Russia": "RS"
},
"countries": {
  "AE": {
    "currencies": {
    "AED": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "AL": {
    "currencies": {
    "ALL": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "AU": {
    "currencies": {
    "AUD": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "US": {
    "currencies": {
    "USD": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "GB": {
    "currencies": {
    "EUR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "FR": {
    "currencies": {
    "EUR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "JP": {
    "currencies": {
    "JPY": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  },
  "RS": {
    "currencies": {
    "RSD": {
      "isDefault": false
    }
    }
  },
  "ZA": {
    "currencies": {
    "ZAR": {
      "isDefault": true
    }
    }
  }
  }
};

function getData() {
const myArr = Object.keys(myJSON.countries).map((k) => (Object.keys(myJSON.countries[k].currencies)[0]));
console.log(myArr);    

  for(var i=0; i< myArr.length; i++) {
  el = document.createElement('option');
  el.textContent = myArr[i];
  el.value = myArr[i];
  elem.appendChild(el);
  } 


}
```

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
<br />
<select id="currencyList">

</select>
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: "*I primarily need to use ES6 methods. I wouldn't want to use any other iterators.*" - Huh? Your current code uses ES5 only.

Comment: map & filter are ES6 methods.

Comment: `.map()` and `.filter()` are ES5, not ES6.  They have been around for a long time (since 2009).

Comment: what are you expecting? If you pass the US it should return USD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a country code you can use array syntax to access the tree of JSON for the country.  (you may want to check if the code exists first)

```
// You could get the country code from an HTML element if you wish
const countryCode = "US";
const myArray = Object.keys(myJSON.countries[countryCode].currencies);
console.log(myArray); // ["USD"]
```